Build up a TikZ graphic node by node
I'm creating flowcharts for a presentation. I'd like to build them up slowly during the presentation, i.e a node & arrow at a time for each slide so that it's easier to follow.
So far I'm using something similar to this MWE:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {first};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {first};
    \node at (0,-1) {second};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I'm getting along well with that. However, I'm wondering whether there is a nicer way to do this? (I didn't find anything with some DuckDuckGo or Stackexchange searches nor in the documentation - even though I might very well have missed something considering how powerful TikZ is.)
Something like at \ignoreeverythingfromhereonwards that skips everything until the next \end{tikzpicture} and starts a new TikZpicture afterwards, this time compiling until the next \ignoreeverythingfromhereonwards. Something like this:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{coolpackage}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {first};
\ignoreeverythingfromhereonwards
    \node at (0,-1) {second};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


If you are creating the flowchart for a presentation, you could use beamer overlays to uncover the different elements step by step.
TikZ nodes are overlay-aware. This mean the simplest form of animation would be \node<2-> ... etc.
To have a bit more control and avoid jumping texts, you could use the overlay-beamer-styles TikZ library:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {first};
    \node[visible on=<2->] at (0,-1) {second};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



As I'm just creating the graphics for a presentation in LaTeX but the actual presentation elsewhere I've not considered using the beamer class. This seems to work well however do you know whether there is an option without needing to use beamer?

@Tork If you remove the navigation symbols and make the background transparent, you can use the individual pages of the beamer document as images in whatever tool you use for your presentation. That's not much different than using the standalone class to create images.
